# OpenGL object load in reverse

Tags: opengl, c++, rotation, lighting, model-loader

I am trying to load a model and it is loading it in reverse. When I am trying to rotate it 180 degrees it changes the lightning as well. 
I am not sure what I need to do to change the position that eh model is facing when is being loaded.

This is the object loader:

```
if (!submarineShader->load("BasicView", "glslfiles/basicTransformations.vert", "glslfiles/basicTransformations.frag"))
{
    cout << "failed to load shader" << endl;
}
glUseProgram(submarineShader->handle());  // use the shader

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

cout << " loading model " << endl;
if (objLoader.loadModel("submarine_/submarine v2/submarine5.obj", model))//returns true if the model is loaded, puts the model in the model parameter
{
    cout << " model loaded " << endl;

    model.calcVertNormalsUsingOctree();  

    model.initDrawElements();
    model.initVBO(submarineShader);
    model.deleteVertexFaceData();

}
else
{
    cout << " model failed to load " << endl;
}
```

[image: Model in reverse position]

[image: Correct position of the model]

Comment: My gut feeling is that your function to compute normals is wrong, try it with a very simple shape that can be hand written, like a cube, and see how it behaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by editing my model and with 3dsmax and change it's position.

Comment: What position was needed to fix the problem? How did you identify the need to correct the position?

Comment: it was not position correctly when I open it with 3DSmax, what I did is I just translate it a bit until it was perpendicular with the x and y axis at (0,0) and then exported it.